# How to merge checked out commit to main branch in Git?

Tags: git, github

[image]To explain my question, please see the example.

I have a local repository with a text file called Text1.txt. Now, I have created a new text file called Text2.txt. I use the 'git add Text2.txt' to add and "git commit -a -m "Added text file" to commit the change to the local repository. In this scenario, I wanted to go back to a previous revision. Instead of the git reset command, I used 'git checkout commithash' to go back to the revision. Now that, since my head is pointing at the revision which I checked out, How to incorporate these changes to the main?

I am using GitBash to execute commands. When I used 'git checkout' to revert to a particular revision, since the head pointing to main has changed, the branch name shows something like (10275e2...). Using git merge to merge a branch with the name like this did not seem sensible.

(Please forgive me for being naive; I am new to Git and am more familiar with SVN, which might be the reason for me to find difficulty in wrapping around git concepts and way of working).

Comment: Seems like you are trying to over-complicate it, if so use @matt's answer.  If all you want is publish your changes for everyone, then do `git push origin`.  If there are already changes in main and you want to get those changes down, then do `git pull origin` (then do a push when ready to publish your changes for everyone else)

Comment: @Jason: I have edited the question to add a screenshot of the steps that I have carried out. When I performed the 'git checkout commit hash' operation, my head is not pointing to the main. Thus, git push origin says 'You are not currently on a branch'. I am assuming this is because the head is detached. So, the above solution did not work for me.

Comment: You don't need a screenshot image: you could simply copy-paste the text. The image just shows what Matt already said though, that you're in detached HEAD mode. If it were copyable text, it would be easy for us to show you the exact commit number, but it isn't, so it isn't. (It looks like Matt read the text and re-typed-in the commit hash ID to update his answer. Beware typos, but that's still the answer.)

Comment: @Abhijith.M What are you trying to do?  If all you want is to get rid of your commit, then just `git reset --hard 1f73250` since you're already in main

Answer (score 3):

You are in detached head mode. You only made one commit and all it did was to add a file, so it is sufficient to cherry pick it. So go back to `main` (so you're on a real branch and not in a detached head), and cherry pick your commit:

```
git switch main
git cherry-pick 1f73250
```

That takes you from this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E (main)
           \
            1f73250
```

To this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- copy-of-1f73250 (main)
           \
            1f73250 [abandoned]
```

If the situation had been more complicated, e.g. with more commits that you wished had been on the real branch, things would have been a little more complicated, but only a little.

Comment: I have edited the question to add a screenshot of the commands that I executed. I am assuming that the alphanumeric string that you showed in the answer represents a commit hash. However, I wanted to know if I can have the head point to main with the commit to which I have checked out.

Comment: No pictures of code, please. That is _text_ — copy and paste it, formatted, right into your question.

Comment: If the goal, instead of what I show, is to throw away the existing D and E and just have `main` point to `1f73250`, then you would simply `git switch main; git reset --hard 1f73250`.